# User CRUD permission for content builder in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, administration, content-builder, user-management

Is it possible in Marketing cloud to have folder-based user role for CRUD operations in both Email Content Builder and Data Extention as well? So, for example a user A will only have access to create , edit, read or delete only a certain specified folder. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per SFMC [roles and permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_roles.htm&type=5) no way to restrict the permissions based upon folders either in data extension or content builder.

You can control CRUD operations at the user level only.

For shared data extension or content builder, you can control the access with respect to business unit at folder level and also you can select which user can able to do CRUD operations at user level.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

as correctly stated in answer 1, there is no folder-based permission system unfortunately.
The only possible differentiation is that you can have separate logics for "Shared" and "Local", which is possible for both Content and DEs.

So a potential workaround for your example (of course, sharing is used for other things if you have several BUs, so be careful):

Assumption: you need 2 permission levels, you have a system with only one BU.

-Your level 1 users get full access to Shared and Local

-Your level 2 users get only view access to Shared, and full access to Local.